# .vbs to check one log and write to another

Tags: logging, vbscript

I have my router set to WoL 2 Systems at 0800 daily, except sometimes it doesn't...

To combat this I have written a script to run on my server (always on) to ping said systems, WoL them if down and leave a log file.

I would like to know when this has happened, so I am trying to write a script that will monitor the WoL log, run on a schedule hourly on the above 2 systems + 2 laptops.

I would like this script to write to it's own log, so once it has been acknowledged once (on any system, it will not show a popup again.

FYI here's the Server WoL script, which is working. WoLSystemIfDown.vbs

```
Const ForAppending = 8

Dim outLogFile
Dim strMserverAlive, strWorkstationAlive, strText

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strComputerName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%COMPUTERNAME%" )

Function PingM(strMServer)

Dim objExecObject

Set objExecObject = WSHShell.Exec _
    ("%comspec% /c ping -n 3 -w 1000 24.12.46.11")

    Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
        strText = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadAll()
        If Instr(strText, "Reply") > 0 Then
        ' do nothing
        Else
            set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
            shell.Run "wolmserver.bat"
            objFile.WriteLine
            objFile.Write Date & " - Media Server was dead when pinged @ " & Time & ", WoL Command was sent from " & strComputername
        End If 
    Loop

End Function

Function PingW(strWorkstation)

Set objExecObject = WSHShell.Exec _
    ("%comspec% /c ping -n 3 -w 1000 24.12.46.12")

    Do While Not objExecObject.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
        strText = objExecObject.StdOut.ReadAll()
        If Instr(strText, "Reply") > 0 Then
        ' do nothing
        Else
            set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
            shell.Run "wolworkstation.bat"
            objFile.WriteLine
            objFile.Write Date & " - Workstation was dead when pinged @ " & Time & ", WoL Command was sent from "  & strComputername
        End If 
    Loop

End Function

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("ServerWoLLog.txt", ForAppending)


PingM(strMServer)

PingW(strWorkstation)
```

This code appears to work fine, although you can see where I have commented out "do nothing" twice. It wouldn't work with this or anything else in there.

The log output from this script looks like this

```
21/12/2013 - Workstation was dead when pinged @ 20:02:38, WoL Command was sent from SERVER
23/12/2013 - Workstation was dead when pinged @ 20:02:38, WoL Command was sent from SERVER
23/12/2013 - Media Server was dead when pinged @ 20:35:54, WoL Command was sent from SERVER
24/12/2013 - Media Server was dead when pinged @ 15:35:54, WoL Command was sent from SERVER
24/12/2013 - Workstation was dead when pinged @ 17:07:19, WoL Command was sent from N145
```

As I said, I would like to be made aware when the router fails to WoL these systems, but not repeatedly throughout the day, so I would like this script to check whether or not it had been acknowledged already, then display a popup informing me regarding which system failed to wake.

```
Const ForAppending = 8
Const ForReading = 1

Dim objFSO,objFile,objOutFile
Dim strLine, strMsgDisplayed, strMserver, strWstation, strToday

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("MsgLog.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objOutFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objOutFile.ReadLine
    strMsgDisplayed = Instr(strLine,(date))
Loop

    if strMsgDisplayed Then
    wscript.quit
    End if

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("MsgLog.txt", ForAppending)
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("WoLLog.txt", ForReading)


Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    strToday = Instr(strLine,(date))

Loop

If strToday Then
    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    strMserver = Instr(strLine, "Media Server")
    strWstation = Instr(strLine, "Workstation")
    Loop
End If


    if strMserver Then
    Wscript.Echo "DD-WRT Router Failed to WoL Media Server Today:" & Date & vbNewLine _
    & "" & vbNewLine _
    & "WoL command was sent from Server Instead. Check ServerWolLog.txt for more details"
    objOutFile.WriteLine
    objOutFile.Write Date
    if strWstation Then
    Wscript.Echo "DD-WRT Router Failed to WoL Workstation Today:" & Date & vbNewLine _
    & "" & vbNewLine _
    & "WoL command was sent from Server Instead. Check ServerWolLog.txt for more details"
    objOutFile.WriteLine
    objOutFile.Write Date
    End if
    End if

Wscript.Quit
```

I really appreciate anybody taking the time to read this post, and any help or suggestions would be most welcome.

Merry Christmas Everybody!

Comment: I just made it a lot neater, the problem is I am only reading the last line of the wollog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!! Much more rewarding that way.

I went with

```
Const ForAppending = 8
Const ForReading = 1

Dim objFSO, objFile, objOutFile
Dim strLine, strMsgDisplayed, strMserver, strWstation, strComputer
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strComputer = "24.12.46.10"

Public Function IsAlive(strComputer)

Dim objPing, objStatus
Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}")._
    ExecQuery("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '"_
        & strComputer& "'")

For Each objStatus in objPing
    If IsNull(objStatus.StatusCode) or objStatus.StatusCode<>0 Then 
        Wscript.Quit
    Else
        Exit Function
    End If

    Next
End Function

IsAlive(strComputer)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("//24.12.46.10/c\CheckWoLStatus\MsgLog.txt", ForReading)

Do Until objOutFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objOutFile.ReadLine
    strMsgDisplayed = Instr(strLine,(date))
Loop

    if strMsgDisplayed Then
    wscript.quit
    End if

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("//24.12.46.10/c\CheckWoLStatus\MsgLog.txt", ForAppending)
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("//24.12.46.10/c\CheckWoLStatus\ServerWoLLog.txt", ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll

    If Instr(strText, date & " - Media Server") Then
    Wscript.Echo "DD-WRT Router Failed to WoL Media Server Today: " & Date & vbNewLine _
    & "" & vbNewLine _
    & "WoL command was sent from Server Instead. Check ServerWolLog.txt for more details"
    objOutFile.WriteLine
    objOutFile.WriteLine date
    If Instr(strText, date & " - Workstation") Then
    Wscript.Echo "DD-WRT Router Failed to WoL Workstation Today: " & Date & vbNewLine _
    & "" & vbNewLine _
    & "WoL command was sent from Server Instead. Check ServerWolLog.txt for more details"
    objOutFile.WriteLine
    objOutFile.WriteLine date
    End If
    End If


Wscript.Quit
```

This has the added bonus of pinging the server first, handy for the laptops if they are not on my home network...

Hopefully this is useful for somebody sometime!

Merry Christmas to all, and to all a good night...